# Abbreviations URTI and GE in a doctor's diagnosis

Tags: diagnosis, med-symbol-abbreviations

What do the two abbreviations in "Diagnosis: urti, ge" mean?

URTI is presumably Upper Respiratory Tract Infaction, but what does GE stand for? Could it be related to Diarrhea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**URTI** is a common abbreviation for upper respiratoty tract infection and
**GE** for gastroenteritis, which refers to infection of the stomach and intestine, which is usually associated with diarrhea.

An example of the usage of URTI and GE in a [PubMed article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26603247). This source should not be used to make any conclusions about the cause.